# PHP/Apache rewrite rules with multiple parameters?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got the difficult when rewrite rules with multiple parameter,to modify a URL to SEO-friendly.

My URL:

```
http://domain/cat.php?alias=canon&sort=price&page=3
```

I want to have a rewrite rule so that the following:

`http://domain/c/canon?sort=price&page=3`

Heres my current rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^c/([a-z,0-9-]+)$ cat.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-z,0-9-]+)?sort=([a-z]+)$ cat.php?alias=$1&sort=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-z,0-9-]+)?sort=([a-z]+)&page=([0-9]+)$ cat.php?alias=$1&sort=$2&page=$3 [QSA]
```

I try to get the params but it doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas on which rewrite rules to use?

Thank you!
--hatxi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^c/([a-z,0-9-]+) cat.php?alias=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Should be enough. The `QSA` flag will take care of passing the `sort` and `page` parameters.

Your rules don't work because of the `[L]` flag on the first one, it just discards the rest because it always matches first.